# Local HTML files with simple OpenLayers maps will not open in IOS but will open on all other platforms

Tags: javascript, html, ios, openlayers

I am currently using OpenLayers to send maps to friends and fellow disaster relief volunteers via email.  Below is a very simple example of the code I am using as a basis for displaying the maps.  I save the below code in an html, send it attached to an email, and when they open it as a local html file on their device, it normally opens and displays without a problem.  .

However, about 1.5 years ago, IOS stopped working.  Any clues?

Please, take the time to look at the code.  I did some tracing, and it seems that there's an https reference somewhere in OpenLayers that the IOS webviewer component doesn't like.  Of course, my maps have features added to the source and vector layers, but below is the simplest example just to prove the point that the IOS browser doesn't display the maps, whilst PC, Mac, and Android browsers do.  I've tried saving to a folder and then opening in Chrome on IOS, but still, no joy.

I have used 5.3.0 up until IOS stopped working.  The current version 6.4.3, and it has the same symptoms.

Thanks in advance for your time!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Map</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css' type='text/css'>
    <script src='https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" class="map" >
    </div>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        var mapview = new ol.View({ center: [-11000000, 4600000], zoom: 4  });
        var raster_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            })
        });

        var map;    
        var vector_source = new ol.source.Vector();
        var vector_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vector_source });

        map = new ol.Map({layers: [raster_layer, vector_layer], target: 'map', view: mapview});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you simply replace 6.4.3 with 5.3.0 does it still work?

Comment: No.  (I see that makes the question confusing).  Version 5.3.0 stopped working a while ago.  Neither version will work.  I edited my question so as to remove the confusion.
Thanks for considering the question, however.

Comment: Have you tried using a different source for the scripts?  For example replace `openlayers.org` with
`cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master`

Comment: No...but i will tomorrow morning...

Comment: I replaced the script sources with the cdn.jsdelivr.net references...here are the results

IOS - Fails /
Windows - Works /
Mac - Works /
Android - Works

Here are the steps I took:
1.  Copy the html code above in this forum entry
2.  Create a new html file on my desktop and paste the code
3.  Change the openlayers.org reference with the suggested cdn.jsdelivr reference
4.  Attach the file to an email and send the email
5.  On the above OS's, open the email and open the html file attached to the email
6.   Observe to see if a USA map appears

Everything but IOS shows the map.

Comment: I suspect a security setting in IOS.  Do you have problems with any other html attachments?  Try a basic test with plain html and javascript with no external links, then build on that to see what breaks it.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the suggestion. Am going camping tomorrow, so I will be out of touch for a week. I did, however, go through all of this when things stopped working. It's not my html or javascript that's causing the problem. It's a call to a secure site in one of the openlayers methods that it doesn't like. I will have to set my mac back up to let you know where chrome says the failure is coming from. I just thought someone else may have stumbled on this. Yes, an unusual way of delivering maps, but it works for us. No need to maintain a website and can stuff it into Excel or Google Sheets